# Cauchy's theorem converse

Tags: group-theory

Cauchy's theorem states that if p is a prime dividing the order of a group G, then there is an element of order p. how about if p is a prime the order of an element of a group G, p always divide the order of G?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: We know by Lagrange's theorem that order of a subgroup divides the order of the group. Take the subgroup generated by the element of order $p$.

Comment: can't you just say yes or no?

Comment: Can't you just switch your brain on?

Comment: @jevie voldemort's answer should make "yes" or "no" immediate. It's appropriate for you to have to put the final pieces together, and this will help you to understand the material better. ("Thank you" would also be a more appropriate response, although generally the best way to say thank you is with a +1).

Comment: i know but you can just say yes or no. period

Comment: @jack mother looser

Comment: @jevie why don't you say what you think based on voldemort's answer (with a clear explanation as to why). I'll assess your argument once you've given it.